How to use bind -x and redraw the line in bash readline?
I'm using bind -x in vi-command mode to remap a keyboard character to a direct bash command, which in my case alters the current line (cd ..). Is there a way to at the same time map with -x AND execute the inbuilt redraw-current-line command?
So this is what I have:
bind -m vi-command -x '"-": "cd .."'

This works halfway, then I tried this:
bind -m vi-command -x '"-": "cd .."'` "-":redraw-current-line

But this doesn't work, I think the whole command is now flawed and readline goes back to the custom shortkey for - which is to scroll history. Is there a workaround for this?

Here you said "the line is still stuck at the old dir", but that's just the prompt, right? The command, if you execute it, will be executed in the new directory

https://superuser.com/a/1662149/334516 indicates that redraw-current-line isn't going to help if you want the prompt to be re-evaluated.

Example of how I get bash to re-eval/re-draw the prompt after a bind -x command (to cd .. in this case).
    # Alt-Up to cd .. to parent dir
    bind -x '"\e[1;3A":"cd ..; kill -INT $$"'



That's  actually a great idea, need to try this out!
